# HTML text style shortcuts functioning within Github repository file edits?

Tags: html, github, editor, italic

I am just starting to learn Javascript, and I have a small question about editing files within a Github repository.

I am writing functions within a file in my repository that involve mathematical equations, and I am finding that within the editor itself, it is changing the style of the text based on common HTML shortcuts. In my case, whenever I use the asterisk key, `*`, to multiply values, the editor file will show all text between two consecutive asterisks in italics. It doesn't change the nature of the code itself at all, so it's just a QOL issue for me personally. It's just strange to see blocks of my code appearing italicized within the editor.

Is there any way to have HTML not try and parse such characters as text style shortcuts within the Github repository file editor?

Comment: Which file extension does your file have? Is it `.js`, `.html` or `.md`?

Comment: It's a .md file. Would one of the other two extensions work better in this respect?

Comment: If you are writing Javascript code, then you should use `.js`.

Comment: Cool. `.md` was the extension used for the basic README file when i opened a new repository, and I have just been working in that file. I'll create a `.js` file and work in there from now on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `.js` file extension for Javascript code.

In `README.md` file put basic description for your project. [Basic guid how to write README.md](https://opensource.guide/starting-a-project/#writing-a-readme)